# Finding the lost Cryptocurrency

Tags: wallet

I have a Ledger Nano S wallet with some cryptocurrencies init such as bitcoin.

I tried to update this wallet. But after that, I can not see my cryptos on the wallet. I used 24-words phrases in order to recovery but the wallet proposed the new phrases. I reset my wallet again with these new words unfortunately now I can not find my cryptos.

Please let me know what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to perform a [factory reset](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017582434) and re-try

The [manufacturers instructions](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005434914-Restore-from-recovery-phrase) for wallet recovery are are:

> Step 1. Restore from recovery phrase
>
> 1. Connect the Ledger Nano S to your computer using the supplied USB cable. Your device should display Welcome to Ledger Nano S. If you are setting up your device for the very first time, please contact us if the device immediately asks for a PIN code. It may not be safe to continue using this device.
> 2. Press the left or right button to navigate through the on-screen instructions.
> 3. Press both buttons simultaneously to choose the option Restore from recovery phrase.
>
> Step 2. Choose your PIN code
>
> 1. Press both buttons when Choose PIN code is displayed on the device.
> 2. Press the right or left button to choose the first digit of your PIN code.
> 3. Press both buttons to enter a digit.
> 4. Repeat the process until you've entered 4 to 8 digits.
> 5. Select the checkmark (✓) and press both buttons to confirm the PIN code.
> 6. Use the backspace icon to erase a digit.
> 7. Confirm your PIN code by entering it once more.
>
> Step 3. Enter your recovery phrase
>
> 1. Choose the length of your recovery phrase (12, 18 or 24 words). Press both buttons to validate.
>      Select the correct recovery phrase length and always enter all recovery words.
> 2. Press both buttons when Enter word #1 is displayed.
> 3. Enter the first letters of word #1 by selecting them with the right or left button. > 1. Press both buttons to validate each letter.
> 4. Choose Word #1 from the suggested words. Press both buttons to validate it.
> 5. Repeat the process until the last word of your recovery phrase. To correct a mistake, you can restart from a previous word from the suggested words menu.
> 6. Your device will display Processing and then Your device is now ready once you've successfully restored your private keys.
> 7. Press both buttons to access the Dashboard. The Dashboard is where you can access the apps and settings on your device.

If you are having trouble following this procedure you should [contact Ledger support](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)